# 42P07: relation "users" already exists

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, миграция

Пытаюсь добавить новую таблицу через Миграцию, но получаю ошибку, что users уже существует.

Моя последовательность действий была такова : dotnet ef migrations remove -> Ручное очищение БД, через терминал postgres -> dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigrations -> dotnet ef database update(Ошибка!)

Хотя в самой БД, никаких таблиц нет, перед этим были также ошибки, уже отчаявшись, я сношу БД, и создаю новую, без каких любо таблиц, но при попытке обновить БД, получаю такую ошибку:

fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
Failed executing DbCommand (17ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
role text NULL,
username text NULL,
password_hash text NULL,
email text NULL,
encryption_key text NULL,
api_key text NULL,
CONSTRAINT "PK_users" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Failed executing DbCommand (17ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
role text NULL,
username text NULL,
password_hash text NULL,
email text NULL,
encryption_key text NULL,
api_key text NULL,
CONSTRAINT "PK_users" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: relation "users" already exists

   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|234_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 42P07
    MessageText: relation "users" already exists
    File: heap.c
    Line: 1148
    Routine: heap_create_with_catalog

42P07: relation "users" already exists
```

Хотя БД чистая, и не содержит никаких таблиц

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот модель файла:

```
public class UserFileModel
{
    public string? fileId { get; set; }
    public string? file_path { get; set; }
    public string? file_name { get; set; }
    public string? status { get; set; }
    public int? result_scan { get; set; }
    public string error_message { get; set; }
    public string enc_time { get; set; }
    public string dec_time { get; set; }
    public string upload_time { get; set; }
    public string download_time { get; set; }

    public int? id { get; set; } // Внешний ключ

    [ForeignKey("id")]
    public UserModel User { get; set; } // Навигационное свойство
}
```

Вот модель пользователя

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public string? role { get; set; }
    public string? username { get; set; }
    public string? password_hash { get; set; }
    public string? email { get; set; }
    public string? encryption_key { get; set; }
    public string? api_key { get; set; }
}
```

Вот класс контекста

```
public class FileCryptDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserFileModel> Files { get; set; }

    public FileCryptDbContext(DbContextOptions<FileCryptDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserFileModel>()
            .HasOne(f => f.User)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.id);
    }
}
```

И вот такой вот ModelSnapShot создается при миграции.

```
[DbContext(typeof(FileCryptDbContext))]
partial class FileCryptDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
{
    protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
        modelBuilder
            .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "7.0.10")
            .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 63);

        NpgsqlModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityByDefaultColumns(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity("FileCryptWeb.Models.UserFileModel", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int?>("id")
                    .HasColumnType("integer");

                b.Property<string>("dec_time")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<string>("download_time")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<string>("enc_time")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<string>("error_message")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<string>("fileId")
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<string>("file_name")
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<string>("file_path")
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<int?>("result_scan")
                    .HasColumnType("integer");

                b.Property<string>("status")
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<string>("upload_time")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.HasKey("id");

                b.ToTable("files");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("FileCryptWeb.Models.UserModel", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int?>("id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("integer");

                NpgsqlPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityByDefaultColumn(b.Property<int?>("id"));

                b.Property<string>("api_key")
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<string>("email")
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<string>("encryption_key")
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<string>("password_hash")
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<string>("role")
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<string>("username")
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.HasKey("id");

                b.ToTable("users");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("FileCryptWeb.Models.UserFileModel", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("FileCryptWeb.Models.UserModel", "User")
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("id")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .IsRequired();

                b.Navigation("User");
            });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось достаточно очевидно, и просто. Я после удаления миграций, не обновлял БД. Так что ввод этой команды решил все проблемы.

```
dotnet ef database update
```

Т.е не нужно было очищать бд вручную, правильная последовательность команд такова:

```
dotnet ef migrations add MigrationName
dotnet ef database update
```

Но если вы уже очистили бд вручную, последовательность будет таковой:

```
dotnet ef database update
dotnet ef migrations add MigrationName
dotnet ef database update
```

Comment: То есть ошибку применения миграций вы решили … применив миграции? Сдаётся мне, вы скрыли либо не увидели какую-то важную деталь, без .которой что проблема, что решения выглядят полным бредом.

Comment: Эта ошибка была из-за того что я откатывал миграции/удалял миграции, и очищал БД (В самом терминале postgres), но после отката миграций, я не обновлял БД через database update, что приводило к тому что в что к тому что вылезала ошибка, что 'users' уже существут.

Т.е таковыми были мои действия до решения проблемы: Ручное удаление миграций/Откат через dotnet ef migrations remove -> Ручное очищение БД -> dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigrations -> dotnet ef database update(Ошибка). Из этой последовательности нужно было всего лишь ввести команду dotnet ef database update после очищения БД.

Comment: Но вообще, как я знаю, такого быть не должно. Не нужно БД очищать, и после удалять старые миграции. Но в моем случае это помогло. @PavelMayorov